# Compare 3 lists

Tags: vb.net

I have `Listbox1` with filenames,
`Listbox2` and `Listbox3` with some other filenames.

Now i need to check if items in `Listbox1` is found in Listbox2

- if found in `Listbox2` do nothing
- if not found in `Listbox2` then search `Listbox3`,
- still not found then add item to Listbox2

That next item from `Listbox1`, do the same and so on.

How to do that most clever?

Comment: A lot of loops, but dont know how to read the elements in listbox, or do i , think i have an idea.

Comment: Hopefully you're not trying to do that with an actual cleaver! :)

Comment: It seems so complex... Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to add file-names from `ListBox1` to `ListBox2` which are neither in `ListBox2` nor in `ListBox3`. [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) both lists and use  [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
Dim otherPaths = Listbox2.Items.Cast(Of String).Concat(Listbox3.Items.Cast(Of String))
Dim onlyInListbox1 = Listbox1.Items.Cast(Of String).Except(otherPaths)
For Each path In onlyInListbox1
    Listbox2.Items.Add(path)
Next
```